# How to limit interface{} for specific types

Tags: go

I am using Go and I have a factory function that returns different types of objects, depending on a requested identifier:

```golang
func NewObject(id string) interface{} {
    switch id {
    case "truck":
        return Truck{}
    case "car":
        return Car{}
    ....
    }
}
```

Here are the respective struct types:

```golang
type Truck struct {
    Foo string
}

type Car struct {
    Bar string
}
```

As you can see, Truck and Car don't have anything in common. The problem arises from the fact that I now have to deal with the too broad type `interface{}` when calling `NewObject(..)`. I know there are generics, but this would require to keep a list of all supported types in the type constraints that would complicate things in my code base.

Basically I am looking for a way on how to use inheritance here which Go of course doesn't support. What would be the alternative?

Comment: If there is nothing in common, inheritance would not help either. A common trick for this is to use a marker interface containing an unexported method, and a default empty implementation of it. Any struct that can be returned from that factory embeds the struct thus implementing that marker interface.

Comment: That's a nice idea, a marker interface. I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking exactly. If `Truck` and `Car` have nothing in common, then how can `interface{}` be too broad of a type? And how could "inheritance" (you probably mean a particular way of doing this in another language) solve this, since they have nothing in common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NewObject(..)` function can be implemented with the support of **generics**. You don't need to keep a list of all supported types in the type constraints.

```golang
func NewObject[T any](id string) T {
 var vehicle any

 switch id {

 case "truck":
  vehicle = Truck{
   Foo: "foo",
  }
 case "car":
  vehicle = Car{
   Bar: "bar",
  }
 }

 if val, ok := vehicle.(T); ok {
  return val
 }

 var otherVehicle T
 fmt.Printf("Not implemented. Returning with default values for \"%v\"\n", id)
 return otherVehicle
}
```

You can see complete example [here](https://go.dev/play/p/-0GG0SwsDvK).

Answer (score 1):

I have an odd example

This example will return `construct of struct`

Hope this inspire you

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type testA struct {
    a uint
}
type testB struct {
    b string
}

var mp map[string]func(...interface{}) interface{} = map[string]func(...interface{}) interface{}{
    "struct1": func(para ...interface{}) interface{} {
        return &testA{
            a: para[0].(uint),
        }
    },
    "struct2": func(para ...interface{}) interface{} {
        return &testB{
            b: para[0].(string),
        }
    },
}

func NewSpecial(type_check_str string) func(...interface{}) interface{} {
    if val, ok := mp[type_check_str]; ok {
        return val
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {

    test1 := NewSpecial("struct1")(uint(5))
    test2 := NewSpecial("struct2")("It's Ok?")
    fmt.Println(test1)
    fmt.Println(test2)
}
```